# Is there any postgreSQL function to calculate mathematical metrics under certain conditions

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

| Call_ID | UUID | Intent_Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | Loan_BankAccount |
| A | 234 | StopCheque |
| A | 123 | request_agent |
| B | 900 | Loan_BankAccount |
| B | 123 | request_agent |

I have the above table with me:
where "Call_ID" means a call that has been made, "UUID" means a particular query that has been asked in the call, and "Intent_Product" means what is the query about.

The expected output is: [Expected_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JKJ3.png)

**Conditions**:

1. Resolved Count :- Count of the total number of queries that has been resolved (here for example "Loan_BankAccount"= 2, "StopCheque" = 1) (here request_agent has to be ignored as those are not resolved)
2. Containment Count :- ((Resolved_Count)x(Total_distinct_calls/total_number_of_turns)) (here for example "Containment_Count" for "Loan_BankAccount" = 2*(2/5) = 0.8

Comment: There is manual and it is for free: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html are good starting points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with t2 as 
(select round(1.0*count(distinct call_id)/count(*), 2) dis_by_calls from t)

select  intent_product
        ,count(*)                   as Resolved_Count
        ,count(*)*max(dis_by_calls) as Containment_Count
from     t, t2 
group by intent_product
having   intent_product <> 'request_agent'
```

| intent_product | resolved_count | containment_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Loan_BankAccount | 2 | 0.80 |
| StopCheque | 1 | 0.40 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tZgCS-f_?hide=4)